# Output in truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc

I want to read the result  of these code  in truffle console . I used truffle v.3.2.5 and testrpc v.3.0.5 If such question  return with two parameter exist then provide me a appropriate link .

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract shapeCalculator {
    function rectangle(uint w,uint h)
    returns (uint s, uint p )
    {
    s=w*h;
    p=2*(w+h);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compile and run your contract in truffle, you can follow below commands -

```
$ truffle console
truffle(development)> compile
truffle(development)> migrate
truffle(development)> contract.new('Argument if Any')

truffle(development)> contract.at("contract address").functionName()
```

Or

```
truffle(development)> contract.at('contract address').functionName("parameter", function (e, result) { if (!e) {console.log(result)}})
```

### **Note: Don't forget to add any new contracts to the migration file.**

More elaborated answer -

You can see return values only from Constant function, so make your function constant -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract shapeCalculator {
    function rectangle(uint w,uint h) constant
    returns (uint s, uint p ){
    s=w*h;
    p=2*(w+h);
    }
}
```

then do the following -

```
$ truffle console
truffle(development)> compile
truffle(development)> migrate
truffle(development)> shapeCalculator.new().then(function(res) { sc = shapeCalculator.at(res.address) })
truffle(development)> sc.rectangle(10,10)
```

Comment: contract.new('Argument if Any')       ----> what does this do ?

Comment: if you have a constructor defined in the contract and that takes some argument, so you can pass them here while instantiating.

Comment: I expect output 100 from the calculation but i get this information as below :-  { tx: '0x652034bc965252bedb9ebf7c2d1c7f8eab5b4d51d59a1954725d64d2d9af4726',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0x652034bc965252bedb9ebf7c2d1c7f8eab5b4d51d59a1954725d64d2d9af4726',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x153882ab5da296a93616b1504f7179fd5e47274a0c53a198e8dc0c71ab2dde6b',
     blockNumber: 36,
     gasUsed: 21662,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 21662,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [] },
  logs: [] }

Comment: In your case, there is no constructor. I gave you a generic solution, you can skip passing argument.

Comment: Also, just to mention. You can get return values only from constant functions. So make your function constant.

Comment: I changed my code to this as below :- pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract shapeCalculator {
 uint w= 10;
    function rectangle  (uint w) constant
    returns (uint s)
    {
    s=w*w;


    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60816/discussion-between-gopal-ojha-and-sanchit).

Answer (score 0):

If your contract is mentioned in the `migrations` file, then use the following:

```
$ truffle console
truffle(development)> compile
truffle(development)> myContract = contract.deployed()

truffle(development)> myContract.then(function(instance){return instance.yourFunctionhere()})
```

Comment: truffle(development)> migrate --reset
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  Migrations: 0x83348f6920e0140837a41f3d433a1786604ed17d
Saving successful migration to network...
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Replacing shapeCalculator...
  shapeCalculator: 0xc082ac94bf3f240558726bc48ad7c82de521b40e
Saving successful migration to network...
Saving artifacts... now the thing is , please write the syntex for this to read output . when i compiled and done as u said it throws the errors .

Comment: @Gopalojha Those are not errors.

Comment: truffle(development)> mycontract.then(function(shapeCalculator){returns shapeCalculator.rectangle()})
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: truffle(development)>  myContract.then(function(shapeCalculator){shapeCalculator.rectangle()}) 
undefined
truffle(development)> (node:5536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a number: [object Object]

Comment: Oh finally i realized your answer @Jossie Calderon . You suggested that not using 'return' . In your syntex  there is 'instance' . how do i create the instance of the contract ? Give me simple contract example with compile syntax .